# How to plot "nlarx" Model of arbitrary input?

Tags: matlab, identification

After system identification by `nlarx` command, how can I obtain the `nlarx` model identified output from my arbitrary inputs?

After `step(nlarxModel)`, command I face this error message and no plot is made:

> Warning: The data cannot be plotted because it is incompatible with the size of the plot or is missing.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.the problem was at in "nlarxModel",bcz of choosing bad orders for the model identification.afdter change it,the "step(nlarxModel)" command goes ok.